# How to jump out of the loop and access previous elements

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

have one XML Structure:

```
<INFO>
<para Type="07">07    L„hetysluettelo</para>
                            <para Type="+0">+0                     074064</para>
                            <para Type="07">07    Tilausnumero            Ostajan viite</para>
                            <para Type="+0">+0                  044275                   5549177</para>
                            <para Type=" 0"> 0    836679586 (LONG               2478      3.63                      8995.14</para>
                            <para Type="07">07    L„hetysluettelo2</para>
                            <para Type="+0">+0                     074517</para>
                            <para Type="07">07    Tilausnumero            Ostajan viite</para>
                            <para Type="+0">+0                  044276                   5534435</para>
                            <para Type=" 0"> 0    836679586 (LONG               2478      3.63                      8995.14</para>
                            <para Type=" 0"> 0    L1 KUORMAL. 800                 14      0.00                         0.00</para>
</INFO>
```

I would like to use loop on para which has type SPACE0. By doing this i would alos like to fetch its previous data elements for example: +0 and 07 segments.

I am looking for this output:

```
<ROWS>
<ROW>
<NUMBER>074064</NUMBER>
<ORDER_NUMBER>044275</ORDER_NUMBER>
<REF>5549177</REF>
<NAME>836679586 (LONG</NAME>
<COUNT>2478</COUNT>
<PRICE>3.63</PRICE>
<TOTAL>8995.14</TOTAL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<NUMBER>074517</NUMBER>
<ORDER_NUMBER>044276</ORDER_NUMBER>
<REF>5534435</REF>
<NAME>836679586 (LONG</NAME>
<COUNT>2478</COUNT>
<PRICE>3.63</PRICE>
<TOTAL>8995.14</TOTAL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<NUMBER>074517</NUMBER>
<ORDER_NUMBER>044276</ORDER_NUMBER>
<REF>5534435</REF>
<NAME>L1 KUORMAL. 800</NAME>
<COUNT>14</COUNT>
<PRICE>0.00</PRICE>
<TOTAL>0.00</TOTAL>
</ROW>
</ROWS>
```

in some cases the elements NUMBER, ORDER_NUMBER, and REF value will remain the same because they belong to same segment.

Is it possible to do this?

I have tried this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="INFO/para[@Type=' 0']">
                    <ROW>

                            <NUMBER>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(../following-sibling::para[1],6,24))"/>
                            </NUMBER>

                                                                        <ORDER_NUMBER>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(../following-sibling::para[3],7,24))"/>
                                </ORDER_NUMBER>
                                <REF>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(../following-sibling::para[3],31,50))"/>
                                </REF>
    <NAME>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(.,7,24))"/>
                            </NAME>
    <COUNT>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(.,33,8))"/>
                            </COUNT>



                        <PRICE>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(.,41,11))"/>
                                                </PRICE>
                                            <TOTAL>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(.,69,11))"/>
                                                </TOTAL>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please check now?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried the nested loop, i.e. on Para with type space0. Its working but i am not able to fetch the its previous elements from this loop

Comment: outer loop was on para with type 07 and innner loop was on type space0

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: Your current output looks absolutely nothing like your expected output. Are you sure you put the correct information in your question? Or is your question that you don't know how to generate any part of your expected output?

Comment: Final result can be anything in terms of element or nodes. If you see order information  I am using following sibling there which are not working. I need to go out of inner loop.

Comment: You can consider the expected output, the logic I am using is mentioned in the code.

Comment: No need to comment on it, i have solved the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using substring functions and nested loops, it worked well. So marking it closed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).